# How to transfer data from Raspberry Pi to server using SFTP or other protocol

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sftp

I want to ask, how to transfer hardware data (CPU, RAM, DISK stats) from Raspberry Pi to online web server using SFTP. I am new in Linux and I have no idea how to do it. I've already had a program in Python which gives me important data, but now I need to send them to web.

Comment: You mean in real time?

Comment: Do you have a display or x in general? Or just command line?

Comment: Depending on how much you know about databases a mysql add-in and connect to mysql database on your destination server.

Comment: I want to use ncFTP software for that. I am able to send file from terminal, but I need a script, which will be sending that file every 30 seconds. 
Here you can find out ncFTP: http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html
Give me please some examples or similar code for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your Python code, collect the data you want to a string.

And then upload the string to a file over SFTP protocol. Use [Paramiko library](https://www.paramiko.org/) for that.

See [Upload a file-like object with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5914761/850848)